# Gproc: Each process just return its own pid when performing lookup_pids

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I tried to regsiter some processes with a famliy name with gproc.
For this reason I created a gen_server that contain two function, the first one is to handle registration and the second one is to lookup Pids of registered processes.
After that, I opened two erlang consoles and I registered two processes with the same property
(each console request the server to register one process)
My server code is as follows:

```
start_link() ->
gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [],[]).

init([]) -> gproc:start_link(), {ok, []}.
%% Synchronous call
register(Pid, Name) ->
gen_server:call(Pid, {register, Name}).

getpids(Pid, Name) ->
gen_server:call(Pid, {getpids, Name}).

handle_call({register, Name}, _From, State) ->
gproc:reg_or_locate({p,l,Name}),
{reply, Name, State};

handle_call({getpids, Name}, _From, State) ->
Pids = gproc:lookup_pids({p,l,Name}),
{reply, Pids, State}.

handle_info(Msg, State) ->
io:format("Unexpected message: pn",[Msg]),
{noreply, State}.

terminate(normal, State) -> 
ok.
```

I registered my processes with

```
server_name:register(PID,<<"test">>)
```

and I lookup the pids with:

```
server_name:getpids(PID,<<"test">>)
```

But when I tried to get the pids of my family processes (Basically I have to pull a list
with 2 pids) I got just one pid (each console just lookup the pid registered by him self
and not render the pid registered with the other console).

Thanks for your help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the right way to start the gproc application is to use:

```
application:start(gproc),
```

Next, I guess that when you say that you are opening 2 erlang consoles, you are starting 2 erlang nodes (in linux running erl in 2 consoles). In this case, you need first to connect the 2 nodes in a cluster, for example:

In console 1

```
erl -sname node1
```

*then you get the erlang shell prompt showing the node name : host_name@node1*

in console 2

```
erl -sname node2
```

*then you get the erlang shell prompt showing the node name : host_name@node2*

still in node 2:

```
true = net_kernel:connect_node('host_name@node1').
application:start(gproc).
```

Now the 2 erlang nodes are connected, and the application gproc is started, you can register processes.

I am not sure that it is correct to use the function `gproc:reg_or_locate/1` in order to register several processes with the same key, I would have used `gproc:reg/1`.

Same thing for the registration context, I would have used global:  `gproc:reg({p,g,Name})`

Comment: I didn't understand why I should link the two process to have a unique register?

Comment: In my case, I have to work with local registration, Is there another solution to have a shared register with gproc within a local scope ?

Comment: What is not clear to me is: do you start 2 erlang shells (you execute erl twice) or do you have 2 shells in the same node using `Ctrl-G` then  `s` and then `c 2`

Comment: In my case, I run 2 erlang shells in 2 different console.

Comment: So you have to use named shells ( for example using the option `-sname`) and connect them. It is necessary to create a cluster of nodes and have the gproc application working. If you don't connect them, the 2 nodes (also named VM) ignore each other and gproc on one node is not aware of processes running on the other node.

Comment: UNDERSTOOD, please can you help me in this issue (my real case)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955313/issue-when-registering-two-local-process-with-gproc-within-cowboy-websocket-hand