# Issue when registering two local process with gproc within cowboy websocket handler

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, cowboy

I tried to register a bunch of processes with a unique family name with gproc under a cowboy websocket handler.
In my handler I created two method, the first one is to handle registration:

```
websocket_handle({text, <<"Reg: ",Message/binary>>}, State) ->
io:format("Client ~p requesting to register ~n",[Message]),
MyPID=list_to_binary(pid_to_list(self())),
{[{_,Family}]}=jiffy:decode(Message),
io:format("Client ~p requesting to register ~n",[Family]),
Test = gproc:reg({p, l, Family}),
erlang:display(Test),
io:format("Registration OK, replying ..."),
Result =  gproc:lookup_pids({p, l, Family}),
erlang:display(Result),
[PID] = Result,
io:format("PASS  ~n"),
io:format("PID ~p FORMATTED ~n",[PID]),
Res= list_to_binary(pid_to_list(PID)),
\"inform\",\"From\" : \"Server\",\"Message\" : \"How you are doing !\"}">>),
{reply, {text,<<"{\"Type\" : \"fb_server\",\"Action\" : \"registration\",\"From\" : \"Server\",\"Message\" : \"",Res/binary,"\"}">>}, State};
```

The second one is to handle pis recuperation:

```
websocket_handle({text, <<"Get: ",Message/binary>>}, State) ->
io:format("Client ~p requesting Pids ~n",[Message]),
{[{_,Family}]}=jiffy:decode(Message),

Result =  gproc:lookup_pids({p, l, Family}),
erlang:display(Result),
if 
    Result == [] ->
       {reply, {text,<<"{\"Type\" : \"fb_server\",\"Action\" : \"Get Pids\",\"From\" : \"Server\",\"Message\" : \"Empty list\"}">>}, State};
    true ->
       [PID] = Result,
       io:format("PASS  ~n"),
       io:format("PID ~p FORMATTED ~n",[PID]),
       Res= list_to_binary(pid_to_list(PID)),
      \"fb_server\",\"Action\" : \"inform\",\"From\" : \"Server\",\"Message\" : \"How you are doing !\"}">>),
      {reply, {text,<<"{\"Type\" : \"fb_server\",\"Action\" : \"Get Pids\",\"From\" : \"Server\",\"Message\" : \"",Res/binary,"\"}">>}, State}
end.
```

To test my handler I created two js files, the first one is to register a process family, I start the registration request as follows:

```
 writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
var msg = {family: "Js"};  
websocket.send("Reg: "+JSON.stringify(msg) );
```

The second test file is to get the pid of process already registered by the first file:

```
function onOpen(evt)
{
//ON opening connection we will send a getPids request to get pids of                 processes registered under Family "Js" 
writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
var msg = {family: "Js"};
//websocket.send("Reg: "+JSON.stringify(msg) );
 getPids(msg);
//doSend("WebSocket rocks");
}
function getPids(msg)
{
writeToScreen("get Pids");
websocket.send("Get: "+JSON.stringify(msg) );
}
```

My problem is that the first file register the process successfully but the second one get en empty list, basically it should get a list with the pid already created by the first file ??

Best regards .

Comment: Are you sure the first websocket is still open when you connect the second client? If the first client closes the socket the erlang process handling that websocket will be killed and the pid will be removed from the gproc registry automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stefan Zobel, you are right,In my onmessage event I have a call to onclose() event.